# What condition should I use to stop a file reading loop?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

The following causes a bug because `file.eof()` apparently doesn't return `true` until a read past the end of the file. How should I be doing this?

```
std::ifstream file("something.stuff", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

while(!file.eof())
{
    double x, y, z;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));  //  Do I need to check if(file) after every read?
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y), sizeof(y));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&z), sizeof(z));

    // Do something with xyz
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just check it after all the reads, unless you intend to do something with partial data, so:

```
while(true)
{
    double x, y, z;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y), sizeof(y));
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&z), sizeof(z));

    if (!file)
        break;

    // Do something with xyz
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, It doesn't cause any harm to keep reading after `(!file)` returns true right?

Comment: @Dave: That is correct.  No harm.  `read()` will check if the stream is in a good state (not eof, fail or bad), if it's not, then it will set `failbit`.  So the worst thing that's going to happen is it will do that two times more than necessary.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: To avoid two times more, you could use `if( !file.read(...) ) break;` for each one. Or rather they all should be in the `while` itself : `while ( file.read(...)  && file.read(...)  && file.read(...) ) { do work; }`. Or maybe a `for`, to limit the scope of the variables : `for(double x,y,z; ... ; ) {}`.

Comment: @Nawaz: I considered all that, but I decided on this solution because it is, IMO, much more readable.  Besides, with those other methods, you're also adding two additional checks for every iteration, whereas with my method, the two extra operations only happen on the last iteration, so there is a tradeoff there. Of course, we're quibbling over micro-optimizations here, my only real consideration was the readability.

Comment: @Nawaz I'm actually reading the size of an array to follow, then allocating that array, then reading into it. There's no way to do that with the structuring you recommend.

Comment: @Dave: Why don't you read a chunk of `(3*sizeof(double))` bytes at once, and then make 3 doubles out of it?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't think that's a response to what I said, but I'll answer anyway: I could, and I should, up until I have to read an array of unknown size. I'll make that change :) I would really like to just put it all in a struct and read it into the struct - but I can't count on padding being the same (grrr).

Answer (score 1):

`std::ifstream::read` should set the `eof` flag once you read past the end of the file.

So, yes, you should just check `file.eof()` after each call to `file.read()`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, find the length of the file upfront using seek and tell, and then calculate how many iterations you should perform. That way you don't have to keep checking the eof bit after every read.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the end of stream could be reached during each read, so you should check if each one succeeds before proceeding

```
std::ifstream file("something.stuff", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary); 

while(!file.eof()) 
{ 
    double x, y, z; 
    if (!file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x)) ||
        !file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y), sizeof(y)) ||
        !file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&z), sizeof(z)))
    {
        // failure... perhaps check file.eof() and/or file.fail() for precise condition
        break;
    }
    else 
    {
        // Do something with xyz 
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if you call another read after the last one flagged eof? Is there any harm done (other than an extra call)?

Comment: Setting `file.read` as the while-condition solved it for me, thanks!